# How do you move the square to whitch it is bieng pressed

Tags: java, swing, project, game-engine

I'm currently working on a project for a snake game, and I need help on moving the Snake Square that I created. This is what I did to create the square:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ShapeTest extends JFrame{
     public ShapeTest(){
          setSize(300,400);
          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          setVisible(true);
     }

     public static void main(String a[]){
         new ShapeTest();
     }

     public void paint(Graphics g){
          g.drawRect(80, 30, 100, 100); // FOR SQUARE
     }
}
```

So now on my main Snake Class I want to move the square sort of like an Action. I would love you all so much if you could help me! Thank you so much!

Here is my main Snake Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ShapeTest extends JFrame{
     public ShapeTest(){
          setSize(300,400);
          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          setVisible(true);
     }

     public static void main(String a[]){
         new ShapeTest();
     }

     public void paint(Graphics g){
          g.drawRect(80, 30, 100, 100); // FOR SQUARE
     }
}
```

Edit: Is this the right path?

```
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do some action
    }
});
```

Thankyou so much i understand now! Love you guys!

Comment: Why is this tagged `android`?.

Comment: Highly sorry, That was an accident :( It showed me like a suggestion

Comment: My suggestions would be to 1) let a `JPanel` hold the graphics (override `paintComponent()`, not `paint()`), 2) make the `Snake`-class have a `draw(Graphics g)` method that draws it, some methods like `moveLeft()`, `moveRight()` etc (in which you change the x/y coordinates), and 3) add [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to the panel, so e.g. when the left arrow-key is pressed it calls `moveLeft` on the `Snake`-instance

Comment: @LuxxMiner Two questions.. First are you trying to say i should put everything on snake class and just forget putting it in two classes. And second how do you change the x/y cordinates? Sorry for the many questions.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "everything" :D I would handle the drawing of the Snake inside the `Snake`-class, yes. *" how do you change the x/y cordinates"* - You could have a `x` and a `y`-variable in the `Snake` class (preferably also `width` & `height`). Implement some getters & setters and then do something like `g.drawRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());` (*The snake class shouldn't extend `JPanel`, if that was what you were thinking about*).

Comment: getters setters? Ok i just edited my code and show you if thats the way im suppose to do it. If you dont mind can you take a look at it and tell me if im going to the right path?

Comment: I have the feeling whe are talking past each other :D Why do you want a `JButton`? (if that is what `b` is). I will just post an example in a few minutes to show what I meant.

Comment: Please translate the title into standard English. I am not quite sure what is meant. Perhaps you mean "How can I move a square which is pressed?".

Answer (score 3):

That is not how you do custom painting. Don't override the paint() method of a JFrame.

Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` of a `JPanel` and then you add the panel to the frame.

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html). The example in the tutorial will show you how to better structure your code. It also shows how to paint a square where you click with the mouse.

Comment: You dont understand how confused i am now. Like what should i do? If i dont disturb you can you just show an example? Thanks!

Comment: @user5600875, I did show you an example. Click on the link, read the tutorial and download the example. I'm not going to copy the code from the tutorial for you.

Comment: Ok Thanks! That helped!

Answer (score 3):

As promised, here is my example. The most important things:

1. I overrode `paintComponent()`, not `paint()`, of a `JPanel`
2. The `Sprite`-class has the variables `x`, `y`, `width`, `height` and the corresponding getters & setters.
3. The `Sprite`-class has the method `draw(Graphics g)` which allows the `panel` to draw the `Sprite`
4. The `Sprite`-class has the methods `moveLeft()`, `moveRight()`, `moveUp()` and `moveDown()`, each changing the `x`/`y` variable accordingly.
5. I added [`Key Bindings`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to the `panel` in order to call the methods mentioned at point `4.` when the corresponding arrow-keys are pressed. Please read the link for a further explanation of Key Bindings.

Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Example();
            }
        });
    }

    public Example() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");

        Sprite sprite = new Sprite(50, 50, 10, 10);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                sprite.draw(g);
            }
        };

        // Key Bindings
        panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "left");
        panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "right");
        panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), "up");
        panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), "down");
        panel.getActionMap().put("left", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                sprite.moveLeft();
                panel.repaint();
            }
        });
        panel.getActionMap().put("right", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                sprite.moveRight();
                panel.repaint();
            }
        });
        panel.getActionMap().put("up", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                sprite.moveUp();
                panel.repaint();
            }
        });
        panel.getActionMap().put("down", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                sprite.moveDown();
                panel.repaint();
            }
        });

        frame.setContentPane(panel);

        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class Sprite {

        private int x, y, width, height;

        protected Sprite(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            setX(x);
            setY(y);
            setWidth(width);
            setHeight(height);
        }

        protected void draw(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
        }

        protected void moveLeft() {
            setX(getX() - 10);
        }

        protected void moveRight() {
            setX(getX() + 10);
        }

        protected void moveUp() {
            setY(getY() - 10);
        }

        protected void moveDown() {
            setY(getY() + 10);
        }

        protected int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        protected void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        protected int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        protected void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }

        protected int getWidth() {
            return width;
        }

        protected void setWidth(int width) {
            this.width = width;
        }

        protected int getHeight() {
            return height;
        }

        protected void setHeight(int height) {
            this.height = height;
        }
    }

}
```